# how can i sort a SQL table using C#.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with tickets system, and whenever i remove a ticket and add a new one, the new ticket comes in the place of the old one with a different ID.

The code which adds a new ticket :

```
public ActionResult BookaTicket(AccApp.Models.TicketsBooked ticketinfo)

        {
                var s = db.TicketsBooked.Create();
                db.TicketsBooked.Add(ticketinfo);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View(ticketinfo);
        }
```

**TicketInfo** is the object that holds the user entries from the view, **Ticketsbooked** is the table name.

and this is how i remove a ticket :

```
public ActionResult Remove(AccApp.Models.TicketsBooked x)
        {
            var TicketToBeRemoved = db.TicketsBooked.Find(x.TicketID);
            db.TicketsBooked.Remove(TicketToBeRemoved);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
```

for example if i remove the ticket with id = 4 and add another ticket, my table would be like :

```
ID : 1      TicketInfo..
ID : 2      TicketInfo..
ID : 3      TicketInfo..
ID : 56     TicketInfo..
ID : 5      TicketInfo..
```

I'm trying to place a **sort** statement (if possible) so its executed every time i add a ticket.

any idea ?

Comment: db.TicketsBooked.OrderBy(x => x.ID)? The order of how the data is stored in the database is usually irrelevant.

Comment: You can sort it in your DB. It's better to change your design. please write more details, to help you better

Comment: is `ID` string or int? If it is string - then you need to convert it to int before duing the sort.. or apply a natural sort to it

Comment: what kind of details. @JensKloster its BigINT.

Comment: OK - then just use `.OrderBy(..)`.. note that it does not change the *Table* - just the result or your query

Answer (score 1):

If you want it sorted just use a simple LINQ statement:

```
var sortedTickets = db.TicketsBooked.OrderBy(tb => tb.ID);
```

*As Stefan mentioned in the previous comments, the way this is stored in the database is irrelevant.*

Comment: well, i placed this statement just before "db.saveChanges();" added a ticket and i went to the table and clicked show table data, still not working..

Comment: Do items of `TicketsBooked` implement `IComparable`? It is needed for sorting

Comment: @user2962142 The way this is stored in the database is really irrelevant. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: its a project for the collage and i need to show the functionality of my system, and i cant do that if every ticket will be placed somewhere i dont know